# clicking images for their detail page

Tags: php

I'm trying to enable a user to go to a post detail page. They can find these images after a search. But I always get this: 
**Warning: Illegal string offset 'postID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eindwerk2\index.php on line 106
Warning: Illegal string offset 'postID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eindwerk2\index.php on line 180**

this is the php code. The seach function works btw.

```
 $_SESSION['KEYWORD'] = array();
$error = '';
//$allResults2 = array();

if (isset($_POST['Find'])) {
try {

    $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imdterest", "root", "");

} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$postTags = $_POST['naam'];

//$pdoQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN user ON posts.postUser = user WHERE postTags = :postTags";

$pdoQuery = "SELECT posts.postID, posts.postUser, posts.postImageUrl, posts.postDescription, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userID FROM posts INNER 
  JOIN user ON posts.postUser=user.email WHERE postTags = :postTags;";

$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":postTags" => $postTags));

if(!empty($_POST)){
    while ($row = $pdoResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $_SESSION['KEYWORD'][] = $row['postImageUrl']['postID'];
        //$poster = $row['postID'];
        //$allResults2[] = $row['postUser'];
        //echo $postTags;


    }
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}

if(count($_SESSION['KEYWORD']) === 0) {
$error = "Sorry no results!";

 }
```

This is the html

```
  <div class="search">
        <?php
        foreach ($_SESSION['KEYWORD'] as $imageLink){

            $postid = $imageLink['postID'];

         echo '<a href=\'./pinSearch.php?postid=$postid\'><img src="' . $imageLink . '"></a>';

        }





        /*foreach ($allResults2 as $imageUser){
            echo  '$imageUser';
        }*/
        ?>

        <div class="searchError"><?php echo $error; ?></div>



    </div>
```

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST)){` why is this only before fetching result ? You execute your query anyway, but that doesn't make sense since you try to bind values from $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is from this line of code:

```
$_SESSION['KEYWORD'][] = $row['postImageUrl']['postID'];
```

This isn't legal syntax in PHP. You can reproduce it with:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    test1 => "Hello",
    test2 => "hello2"
    );
echo $test["test1"]["test2"];
?>
```

When you try to execute this code, you get:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'test2' in

Sadly, I'm not that sure what you try to achieve with this line of code. Anyway, your SQL result is a one-dimensional array. Your code acts like you work with a two dimensional array. You can only use `$row["postImageUrl"]` or `$row["postID"]` you you can't use both directly.

If you describe a bit better what you try to do with this line, I can help you. But actually I have no idea what your thoughts were.

Comment: I was just trying to allow the user to click on an image and get redirected to the detailpage of that image. The images are found by the search function (which works). just ignore $row["postID"], that was just some tryout.

Comment: @ArneBerckmans if you want people to ignore pieces of your code, just leave that out. There's a lot of code you posted here. If you want stackoverflow to help you out, try to narrow down your problem and describe it as short and clear as you possibly can. That way it'll be a lot easier to help out.